# WstxIOException "Invalid UTF-8 start byte" while downloading files using TFS SDK

Tags: java, soap, utf-8, tfs-sdk

I use [TFS SDK for Java](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22616) and randomly get this exception while downloading files from the server:

> com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xab (at char #6473861, byte #6473740)

Has anybody faced it before? Any ideas?

The full stacktrace is below:

> com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xab (at char #6473861, byte #6473740)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.constructFromIOE(StreamScanner.java:599)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:967)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:1006)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.getNextChar(StreamScanner.java:758)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.parseNormalizedAttrValue(BasicStreamReader.java:1862)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleNsAttrs(BasicStreamReader.java:3013)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleStartElem (BasicStreamReader.java:2910)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromTree(BasicStreamReader.java:2786)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1054)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1129)
>    at ms.tfs.versioncontrol.clientservices._03._ItemSet.readFromElement(_ItemSet.java:138)
>    at ms.tfs.versioncontrol.clientservices._03._Repository4Soap_QueryItemsResponse.readFromElement(_Repository4Soap_QueryItemsResponse.java:98)
>    at ms.tfs.versioncontrol.clientservices._03._Repository4Soap12Service$44.readSOAPResponse(_Repository4Soap12Service.java:1214)
>    at com.microsoft.tfs.core.ws.runtime.client.SOAPService.executeSOAPRequestInternal(SOAPService.java:668)
>    ... 28 more
>   Caused by: java.io.CharConversionException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xab (at char #6473861, byte #6473740)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidInitial(UTF8Reader.java:303)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:189)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:84)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:55)
>    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:961)
>    ... 40 more

The source code:

```
 private void overwriteChangedFiles(@NotNull VersionControlClient vc, @NotNull Workspace workspace, @NotNull VersionSpec version, @NotNull String localPath)
 {
    WorkingFolder workingFolder = workspace.getExactMappingForLocalPath(localPath);

    ItemSet itemSet = vc.getItems(m_path, version, RecursionType.FULL, DeletedState.NON_DELETED, ItemType.FILE); // this line sometimes causes exception
```

Comment: What does your code look like, and what file are you trying to download? Are you perhaps trying to download a binary file as if it were text?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: The source code is trivial, I've added it.

Comment: Okay, so nothing specifically text-like. That sounds like a bug in the client code :(